# Can't remove from DBRef set in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have Group objects that have a @DBRef set of Users, and each user likewise has a @DBRef set of Groups:

```
public class Group {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;
    @DBRef(lazy=true)
    private Set<User> users;

    //...
}
```

```
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private Set<Group> groups;
    //...
}
```

When I delete a User I of course have to remove him from his groups:

```
Set<Group> subscribedGroups = userRepository.findByEmail(email).getGroups();
for (Group g : subscribedGroups) {
    Set<User> users = g.getUsers();
    users.remove(user);
    g.setUsers(users); // not sure if this line is necessary but it doesnt work regardless
    groupRepository.save(g);
}
```

This isn't working. `remove(user)` is returning false for some reason. It should be working; I printed the Ids of every member of `users`, then `user.getId()`, then the result of `remove(user)`:

```
List of users:
61abd6f1c81ab948c31641f2

User to delete: 61abd6f1c81ab948c31641f2
Result of removal: false
```

Comment: Spring Data Mongo can be weird. Does `User` override `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: It doesn't override them

Comment: Print out the return value of the `remove` call.

Comment: I already did, see the print statements at the end of my post

Comment: Ah, I understand that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be used to JPA, which employs various means of marvelous magic to ensure that (within a particular transaction) if you see the same database record more than once, you see *the same Java object*, meaning that if (for example) you retrieve a `User` from the `UserRepository` and then see a `Set<User>` somewhere else, you have *the identical object* in both places. In this case, `Collection#remove` will do what you want.

The MongoDB support is different: It just maps POJOs as passive data objects. This means that unless your entity class implements `equals` and `hashCode`, the collection implementations (and anything else) won't consider them equal. You'd need to do something like `removeIf` based on ID.

(This, by the way, is why you need to call `repo.save(changed)` with most repository implementations, even though you don't with JPA specifically.)